# Wide to long dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

There are a lot of questions out there with similar titles but I'm unable to solve the issues that I'm having with my dataset.

**Dataset:**

```
ID   Country Type Region Gender IA01_Raw  IA01_Class1  IA01_Class2 IA02_Raw IA02_Class1 IA02_Class2 QA_Include QA_Comments

SC1  France  A    Europe Male   4         8            1            J         4            1           yes       N/A
SC2  France  A    Europe Female 2         7            2            Q         6            4           yes       N/A
SC3  France  B    Europe Male   3         7            2            K         8            2           yes       N/A
SC4  France  A    Europe Male   4         8            2            A         2            1           yes       N/A
SC5  France  B    Europe Male   1         7            1            F         1            3           yes       N/A
ID6  France  A    Europe Male   2         8            1            R         3            7           yes       N/A
ID7  France  B    Europe Male   2         8            1            Q         4            6           yes       N/A
UC8  France  B    Europe Male   4         8            2            P         4            2           yes       N/A
```

**Required output:**

```
ID   Country Type Region Gender IA Raw Class1 Class2 QA_Include QA_Comments

SC1  France  A    Europe Male   01 K   8      1      yes        N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   01 L   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   01 P   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   02 Q   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   02 R   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   02 T   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   03 G   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   03 R   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   03 G   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   04 K   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   04 A   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   04 P   8      1      yes       N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   05 R   8      1      yes       N/A
....
```

---

In the Dataset I've columns which are names as **IA[X]_NAME** where **X = 1..9** and **NAME = Raw, Class1** and **Class2**.

What I am trying to do is to just **transpose** these columns so that it looks like the table shown in Required output i.e. **IA** will show **X** value and just like this **raw** and **classes** will show their perspective values.

So in order to achieve it I sliced the columns as:

```
idVars = list(excel_df_final.columns[0:40]) + list(excel_df_final.columns[472:527]) #These contain columns like ID, Country, Type etc
valueVars = excel_df_final.columns[41:472].tolist() #All the IA_ columns
```

I don't know if this step was necessary but this gave me the perfect slices of columns  but when I put it in `melt` it is not working properly. I have tried almost every method that is available in other questions.

```
pd.melt(excel_df_final, id_vars=idVars,value_vars=valueVars)
```

I've also tried this:

```
excel_df_final.set_index(idVars)[41:472].unstack()
```

but didn't work and here is Wide to long implementation which also didn't work:

```
pd.wide_to_long(excel_df_final, stubnames = ['IA', 'Raw', 'Class1', 'Class2'], i=idVars, j=valueVars)
```

The error I got for wide to long is:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (95,)
>   (431,)

As my dataset has 526 columns in real, so that is why I've divided them into two lists one contains 95 column names which will be the `i` and the rest 431 are the one that I need to show in the row as shown in the sample data set.

Comment: You are not transposing your dataset. Don't call it "transpose". Transpose is `df.T`.

Comment: Yes but I want to basically convert some column into rows. So I am not able to think of another word.

Comment: Wide to long...

Comment: @cs95 thank you for the correct term. I've updated the question accordingly and I've also implemented it but it didn't worked. Please see now if you can help me solve this.

Comment: It's not going to be easy for anyone to answer because you are expecting a solution for your actual data which has 500 columns. You cannot share a 500 column dataset on this site and reasonably expect a solution from anyone to work for it. It would be more beneficial to you (from a learning perspective), as well as easier to us (because we are unpaid volunteers) if you instead produce a simpler version with not more than 5 columns and explain your problem a little more clearly. See how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yup totally agree as the dataset I've shared is a sample of the 500+ columns which I've also created in an excel sheet to experiment, and if I get a solution of this sample I will be able to convert it to a larger dataset. Have a look I have made it more shorter now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started. The essence is using `set_index`, column conversion to MultiIndex, then `stack`. Better solutions exist, possibly, but I would do it this way because it is an easy step to your output.

```
# Set the index with columns that we don't want to "transpose"
df2 = df.set_index([
   'ID', 'Country', 'Type', 'Region', 'Gender', 'QA_Include', 'QA_Comments'])
# Convert headers to MultiIndex -- this is so we can melt IA values
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, df2.columns.str.split('_')))
# Call stack to replicate data, then reset the index
out =  df2.stack(level=0).reset_index().rename({'level_7': 'IA'}, axis=1)
```

```
out

     ID Country Type  Region  Gender QA_Include  QA_Comments    IA  Class1  Class2 Raw
0   SC1  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       8       1   4
1   SC1  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       4       1   J
2   SC2  France    A  Europe  Female        yes          NaN  IA01       7       2   2
3   SC2  France    A  Europe  Female        yes          NaN  IA02       6       4   Q
4   SC3  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       7       2   3
5   SC3  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       8       2   K
6   SC4  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       8       2   4
7   SC4  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       2       1   A
8   SC5  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       7       1   1
9   SC5  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       1       3   F
10  ID6  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       8       1   2
11  ID6  France    A  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       3       7   R
12  ID7  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       8       1   2
13  ID7  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       4       6   Q
14  UC8  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA01       8       2   4
15  UC8  France    B  Europe    Male        yes          NaN  IA02       4       2   P
```

Comment: @anky_91 Difficult to see how this would scale to 500 columns but I decided to give it a go since the OP has made an attempt to ask a decent question and responded to comments as well... may as well :)

Comment: @cs95 Thank you so much. I did tried and it worked great. However there is one exception but it's because I didn't mentioned it in the question so that's fine. Every `IA` column has another `_` attached to it for example `IA02_Raw_baseline` 'IA02_Raw_midline' etc. I've updated it on sample_sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11HUR8y30CL7sZxsadK2LibwNbN0G6RcwtTl8SAcszHs/edit?usp=sharing if you can edit your answer accordingly I shall be very thankful :)

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha `str.split('_')` should be `str.split('_',n=1)` and then proceed as before.

Comment: @cs95 You are awesome :D Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

u can use `pd.lreshape`

```
pd.lreshape(df.assign(IA01=['01']*len(df), IA02=['02']*len(df),IA09=['09']*len(df)), 
            {'IA': ['IA01', 'IA02','IA09'],
             'Raw': ['IA01_Raw','IA02_Raw','IA09_Raw'], 
             'Class1': ['IA01_Class1','IA02_Class1','IA09_Class1'], 
             'Class2': ['IA01_Class2', 'IA02_Class2','IA09_Class2']
             })


edit : 

pd.lreshape(df.assign(IA01=['01']*len(df), IA02=['02']*len(df),IA09=['09']*len(df)), 
            {'IA': ['IA01', 'IA02','IA09'],
             'Raw': ['IA01_Raw_baseline','IA02_Raw_midline','IA09_Raw_whatever'], 
             'Class1': ['IA01_Class1_baseline','IA02_Class1_midline','IA09_Class1_whatever'], 
             'Class2': ['IA01_Class2_baseline', 'IA02_Class2_midline','IA09_Class2_whatever']
             })
```

edit: Just add `column names` of which ever columns you want from the input in `Raw/Class1/Class2` column of the output to the list inside the dictionary

documentation for this is not available . use `help(pd.lreshape)` or refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482986/how-can-i-pivot-down-my-row-values-for-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe/35483228#35483228)

> Output:

```
    Country Gender  ID  QA_Comments QA_Include  Region  Type    IA  Raw Class1  Class2
0   France  Male    SC1 NaN         yes         Europe  A       01  4   8       1
1   France  Female  SC2 NaN         yes         Europe  A       01  2   7       2
2   France  Male    SC3 NaN         yes         Europe  B       01  3   7       2
3   France  Male    SC4 NaN         yes         Europe  A       01  4   8       2
4   France  Male    SC5 NaN         yes         Europe  B       01  1   7       1
5   France  Male    ID6 NaN         yes         Europe  A       01  2   8       1
6   France  Male    ID7 NaN         yes         Europe  B       01  2   8       1
7   France  Male    UC8 NaN         yes         Europe  B       01  4   8       2
8   France  Male    SC1 NaN         yes         Europe  A       02  J   4       1
9   France  Female  SC2 NaN         yes         Europe  A       02  Q   6       4
10  France  Male    SC3 NaN         yes         Europe  B       02  K   8       2
11  France  Male    SC4 NaN         yes         Europe  A       02  A   2       1
12  France  Male    SC5 NaN         yes         Europe  B       02  F   1       3
13  France  Male    ID6 NaN         yes         Europe  A       02  R   3       7
14  France  Male    ID7 NaN         yes         Europe  B       02  Q   4       6
15  France  Male    UC8 NaN         yes         Europe  B       02  P   4       2
16  France  Male    SC1 NaN         yes         Europe  A       09  W   6       3
17  France  Female  SC2 NaN         yes         Europe  A       09  X   5       2
18  France  Male    SC3 NaN         yes         Europe  B       09  Y   5       5
19  France  Male    SC4 NaN         yes         Europe  A       09  P   5       2
20  France  Male    SC5 NaN         yes         Europe  B       09  T   5       2
21  France  Male    ID6 NaN         yes         Europe  A       09  I   5       2
22  France  Male    ID7 NaN         yes         Europe  B       09  A   8       2
23  France  Male    UC8 NaN         yes         Europe  B       09  K   7       5
```

Comment: Please refer to this sample dataset I've made to see the dataset and the expected outcome: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11HUR8y30CL7sZxsadK2LibwNbN0G6RcwtTl8SAcszHs/edit?usp=sharing and please updated your answer. I shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: updated , assuming your `IA09_Raw` column name is `IA09_Raw_whatever`