# Wide to Long MiltiIndex dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I've solved a part of this question [Wide to long dataset using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801010/wide-to-long-dataset-using-pandas) but still need more help.

I've a dataset which has columns as: 
`IA01_Raw_Baseline`,`IA01_Raw_Midline`,`IA01_Class1_Endline` etc. I want to break it so that the mid word i.e. Raw, Class1 etc remain in the column and IA*x*, *time*Line (mid, base, end) becomes two separate columns. For example for a row of data:

```
ID   Country Type Region Gender IA01_Raw_EndLine  IA01_Raw_Baseline  IA01_Raw_Midline IA02_Raw QA_Include QA_Comments

SC1  France  A    Europe Male   4                 8                  1                         yes       N/A
```

It should become:

```
ID   Country Type Region Gender Timeline IA   Raw Class1 Class2 QA_Include QA_Comments

SC1  France  A    Europe Male   Endline  IA01 4    N/A      N/A yes        N/A
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   Baseline IA01 8    N/A      N/A yes        N/A    
SC1  France  A    Europe Male   Midline  IA01 1    N/A      N/A yes        N/A
```

This is just the conversion of one row where I've 500+ columns which has different **IA** from **01** to **12** and attributes like **Raw**, **Class1**, **Class2**, **Amount** etc all has **baseline** and **midline** etc.

When converting I did break them down to the columns, where I've `idVars` containing columns that will be the index and `valueVars` will have the `IA01_Raw_Baseline` type columns:

```
idVars = list(gd_df.columns[0:40]) + list(gd_df.columns[472:527]) #values that will not pivot
valueVars = gd_df.columns[41:472]#.tolist() #value that will pivot

gd_df2 = gd_df.set_index(idVars)
gd_df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, gd_df2.columns.str.split('_', n=1)))
gd_out =  gd_df2.stack(level=0).reset_index().rename({'level_7': 'IA'}, axis=1)
```

So this code gave me:

[image]

As you can see I got `IA` column the way I wanted but the timeline is still embedded in the column name. **What should I change in my code so that it should give this output**:

[image]

UPDATE:
By doing this:

```
s=df.set_index(idVars)
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple),names =['IA','raw','Timeline'])
s.stack([0,2]).reset_index()
s.to_excel(r'gd_out1.xlsx')
```

I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned wide to long , we using `wide_to_long`

```
s=pd.wide_to_long(df,['IA01_Raw'],i=['ID', 'Country', 'Type', 'Region', 'Gender','IA02_Raw', 'QA_Include',
       'QA_Comments'],j='Timeline',suffix='\w+',sep='_')
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple),names =['IA','raw'])
s.stack(0).reset_index()
Out[27]: 
raw   ID Country Type  Region ...  QA_Comments  Timeline    IA  Raw
0    SC1  France    A  Europe ...          NaN   EndLine  IA01    4
1    SC1  France    A  Europe ...          NaN  Baseline  IA01    8
2    SC1  France    A  Europe ...          NaN   Midline  IA01    1
[3 rows x 11 columns]
```

Update

```
s=df.set_index(['ID', 'Country', 'Type', 'Region', 'Gender', 'QA_Include',
       'QA_Comments','IA02_Raw'])
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple),names =['IA','raw','Timeline'])
s.stack([0,2]).reset_index()
```

Comment: The data I've added in this question is just one row and in total I've 500+ columns which has different IA from 01 to 12 and attributes like Raw, Class1, Class2, Amount etc all has baseline and midline etc. This is why I'm trying to make it look like the last screenshot I've shared. When I run this code I get an error: `tuple index out of range`. It would be great if you can suggest a change in the code that is already splitting `IA` to a separate column. And I not only have Raw, I've Raw, Class1, class2, amount and just like that a lot of things.

Comment: There is no error but the data is in displaying horizontally for some reason. I've added the screenshot in the question please check it.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha assign it back s=s.stack([0,2]).reset_index(), and print